# Syntax to Call Asynchronous Shared Instance Method from Within Closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, closures

I am having trouble with syntax to call a shared instance method from within a closure:

Here is my code:

```
func getContactImage (contact:Contacts, completion:@escaping (_ myimage: UIImage)->()){//open 1 method
    var animg = UIImage(named:"default.png")!

    let surl = "https://~/contactimage.png"
    Utilities.shared.downloadImage(surl: surl as NSString, completion: image as UIImage ->Void in animg = img) 
    completion(animg)
}
```

The line Utilities.shared.downloadImage gives several errors including:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UIAccessibilityTraits' (aka 'UInt64') to type 'UIImage' in coercion

The shared instance method looks like this:

```
@objc func downloadImage(surl: NSString, completion : @escaping (UIImage) -> Void ) {
    //download image
}
```

What is the correct syntax to call the shared instance method from within closure?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should really retire `NS` classes where possible (e.g. use `String` instead of `NSString`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Utilities.shared.downloadImage(surl) {  (img) in

  // use img here
}
```

Also change function

```
@objc func downloadImage(_ surl: String, completion : @escaping (UIImage) -> Void ) { }
```

---

```
func getContactImage (contact:Contacts, completion:@escaping (_ myimage: UIImage)->()){//open 1 method
    var animg = UIImage(named:"default.png")!

    let surl = "https://~/contactimage.png"

    Utilities.shared.downloadImage(surl) { (img) in 
       completion(img)
     }
}
```

BTW encourage using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

Comment: Great.  That worked. Will mark correct when it allows and also check out sdwebimage.